# How can I download all "Style Library" folders and files?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, style-library

I'm searching the easiest way to download all these files.

Sharepoint site only allows me to download one specific file at the time

No solution found searching web.

No matter the way to do it (Powershell, Javascript CSOM, Site etc, Only Not C#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open your library with Internet Explorer
- From the above ribbon Click `Open with explorer` to open the library in file explorer.
- You can now select all files and copy and paste it as you need.

[image]

> **Note:** If the `Open with explorer` is disabled or you got any warning
>   message, [check WE’RE HAVING A PROBLEM OPENING THIS LOCATION IN FILE
>   EXPLORER, ADD THIS WEB SITE TO YOUR TRUSTED SITES LIST AND TRY
>   AGAIN](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/23/were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/)